# Is a comma in this sentence required?

Tags: commas, clauses, syntactic-analysis

In the sentence below, is the comma optional or should it (not) be there? I can hear it there when this is spoken, but I am not convinced it needs to be there in written form.

> In order to pass [...] data protection, the customer must correctly answer [...]

As one could simply reorder the elements of the sentence:

> The customer must correctly answer [...] in order to pass [...] data protection.

and no comma would be needed.

Comment: Hearing it should be your guide. Written language is a symbolic rendering of speech. Punctuation is a symbolic rendering of the flow of speech.

Comment: The fact that you can reorder or reword a sentence to use a certain punctuation tells you little about the proper punctuation of the original. At that point it's a different sentence.

Comment: @WillHunting I agree it is not perfect, [pause] but it is often a pretty good guide. If anything, *additional* punctuation is often required to help organize longer, more complex thoughts, many of which are more convoluted than our nautral speech patterns [like this sentence]. But where there is a natural pause, some punctuation is almost always helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first sentence, it is good to have a comma but not wrong to omit it. In the second, there should not be a comma.

Answer (score 1):

When you use "in order to ..." clause at the beginning, you'd better use a comma before starting the main clause.

Comment: This is a very short answer. It could be improved by adding supporting facts or references. Please see the [faq].